# Android - startActivityForResult immediately triggering onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I am launching activities from the main activity in my app using the call `startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_TYPE)`, and they are all working but one.

This one, when called, launches the activity as desired, but in the log I can see that `onActivityResult()` is immediately being triggered.  The activity shows up but `RESULT_CANCELED` is immediately returned to `onActivityResult()`.

I then interact with the activity, press a button which calls `finish()`, and `onActivityResult()` is not called this time (because apparently a result has already been returned).

Does this make sense to anyone?  Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Answer (score 324, accepted):

You can't use `startActivityForResult()` if your activity is being launched as a `singleInstance` or `singleTask`. `standard` or `singleTop` launch mode will fix the problem.

Comment: `singleTop` seems fine for me, `singleTask` however was causing this issue and hence `singleInstance` would definitely do too

Comment: In my case, did not defined any class as an singleInstance or singleTop, but still it is happening...any suggestion ?

Comment: Note that if the `intent-filter` on the target activity marks it as category `LAUNCHER`, the activity is launched in a new task by default. This can cause the immediately-canceled behavior, even if it is not marked `singleTask` or `singleInstance`.

Answer (score 124):

Additionally make sure the intent does not have the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` set.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK):

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from
>   the activity being launched.

Comment: This fixed the problem in my case. The problem was not caused by singleInstance, singleTop nor singleTask.

Comment: @Diana, do you remember what you used instead of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` ?

Comment: @Keselme Sorry, it's been a long time, I wish I could help but I don't remember and I can't access that code any more.

Comment: Yes, fixed it. startActivityForResult should not be used with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: @hanilozmen what is the intent flag you used. I am having the same issue with gps launcher

Answer (score 21):

I have seen this behavior before, please make sure your destnation activity (that special activity) is not `singleInstance` in AndroidManifest file. If the Activity is `singleInstance`, then it will return `RESULT_CANCELED` before launched!

Answer (score 20):

I'd also like to add that you could call an external app with:
`Intent in = caller.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.your.package.here");`
Which would create an intent with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` added by default, so call:
`in.setFlags(0);`
Which will clear that flag, and then you can proceed to: `startActivityForResult(in, action);`

Reason I'm doing this is that I have a utility app that has common functionality between a few other apps and I can keep the code changes to one location instead of worrying about multiple updates.

Comment: I know this is old, but this was so absolutely invaluable to me that I wanted to say thanks to the user, and point out for anyone jumping between activities that this is freaking gold! Saved my ass during a hackathon ;)

Comment: This is what needs more attention. It is the best solution and works perfectly for me. You saved me a lot of time, thank you so much.

Comment: Up-voting this answer as this was the exact issue I was having this morning! Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Thanks. intent.setFlags(0) solved the problem. Now the second app starts ok and returns result to the calling app

Answer (score 5):

`startActivityForResult()` doesn't work with a `singleInstance` or `singleTask` activity in pre-lollipop version of Android. Since Android 5 it works (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263072/865643) for more details).

Answer (score 5):

It also triggers if you have `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in your intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Thanks. I added FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in my activity.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with the calling activity. Its declaration in the AndroidManifest had the following property:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Changed it to "false" and now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.4 has a small problem about waiting for the return at the end of the actvity closure
To solve this behavior it is important to set :

- all activities will have the **same** task Affinity attribute. (`TaskAffinity = "[SAME STRING]"`)
- `launchmode=singleTop,`
- `launchIntent.SetFlags(0); // for reset default Intent flags if you launch from package manager`

*This solution works with all version of Android*

See this for taskAffinity:
https://asyoulook.com/computers%20&%20internet/android-onactivityresult-being-called-instantly/1004072

Answer (score 1):

Also, check if   android:noHistory="true" on activity in Manifest, if yes, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

For `ActivityGroup` or `TabHost` and others, maybe the `xxxActivity` is a `subActivity` of its parent. Then the `startActivityForResult` can not work but the parent can get the result.

1. call `getParent().startActivityForResult()` from your sub-activity
2. your parent (the `ActivityGroup`) will be able to handle the `onActivityResult`. So I created a subclass of `ActivityGroup` and handled this `onActivityResult`.
3. You can re-route that result back to the sub-activity if you need to. Just get the current activity by `getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()` . My sub-activities inherit from a custom activity so I added a `handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` in that subclass for the `ActivityGroup` to call.

example: http://www.cnblogs.com/relinson/archive/2012/03/25/startActivityForResult.html

Comment: What do you think about this special case when calling default web brower :  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/990063/Why-onActivityResult-can-not-catch-result-from-bro?arn=1

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult()` will also pass `RESULT_CANCELED` as the `resultCode` if you misspell the package or class name in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Manifest set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for activity you want open with result and while opening activity set flag `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`

Answer (score 0):

If you defined `android:noHistory="true"` in the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, it will cause the same issue here.