# Android package installer - how to get "Open" and "Done" and activity result both?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-install-apk, android-launcher

My Android Application has an option to upgrade to the newer version, the newer version APK I keep it available under a path in sdcard. On click of Upgrade option I invoke following method.

```
    public static void launchInstaller(Activity act, String apkPath)
    {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(apkPath)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       act.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

The reason I include FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, is because, after upgradation, I want to have "Open" & "Done" options, which aren't shown if I don't use this flag.

When the above code launches the package installer, it has two options OK & Cancel, when user press Cancel, I want to know user cancelled it. But I am unable to know because the onActivityResult is called pre-maturely. I come to a reason why is that happening after reading the following posts.

[Android - startActivityForResult immediately triggering onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910840/android-startactivityforresult-immediately-triggering-onactivityresult)

[onActivityResult() called prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely)

They ask me to make sure that the Intent I am using to launch the activity doesn't have FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK set on it. See here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

> In particular note: "This flag can not be used when the caller is
>   requesting a result from the activity being launched."
>
> If the activity is being launched as part of a new task then Android
>   will immediately call the onActivityResult() with RESULT_CANCELED
>   because an activity in one task can't return results to another task,
>   only activities in the same task can do so.

But in my case, I can't remove FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, because otherwise I will not get "Open" and "Done" options on successful upgradation.

Has anybody faced similar sort of problem? Kindly help me out, as it drives me nuts.

Comment: I have the same issue...did you get any resolution for this?

Answer (score 4):

You should use package added broadcast intent. Create a broadcast receiver listen [package added.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) 
If added package equals your package, user confirm install otherwise dismiss install process. If you ask what kind extras can be return by android, android returns EXTRA_UID about package. PackageManager' s method convert uid to package.(getPackagesForUid(int uid) returns String array but it usualy return one item in the array in short usually array length equals 1.