# Android -- Camera Intent Returns Immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have an activity that allows the user to select preview a photo that they select from the gallery or the camera.  The problem I'm having is that the camera/gallery intent returns immediately, then shows the camera/gallery and returns nothing.

The basic flow of things is as follows: Fragment -> Application Subclass -> Top Activity -(startActivity)-> Photo Preview Activity -(in onCreate)-> Photo Chooser Intent

---

```
//In the application subclass
public static void launchImageSelector()
{
    if(!(topActivity instanceof ImagePreviewActivity))
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ImagePreviewActivity.class);
        topActivity.startActivityForResult(i, kImageSelectorRequestCode);
    }
}
```

---

```
///in ImagePreviewActivity class
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent());
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent("image/*"));
    startActivityForResult(chooser, 1);
}

//intent creaters(from android src)
private Intent createChooserIntent(Intent... intents)
{
    Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Choose Photo");
    return chooser;
}

private Intent createOpenableIntent(String type) 
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//      i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    i.setType(type);
    return i;
}

private Intent createCameraIntent() 
{
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
            File.separator + "browser-photos");
    cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
    String mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

    photoFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath));

    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoFileUri);

    return cameraIntent;
}
```

---

What am I doing wrong here?  What would cause the Chooser Intent to return immediately but also continue?  Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of debugging the problem was in the Manifest file.  In android, you can't start an activity for a result if the launch mode is set to singleInstance or singleTop

Found the answer here:  [Android - startActivityForResult immediately triggering onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910840/android-startactivityforresult-immediately-triggering-onactivityresult)