# onActivityResult being called before scanning using zxing

Tags: android, zxing

I am integrating the zxing scanner into my android application and I am coming across a weird situation where the onActivityResult (in the activity initiating the scan) is being called before the scanning intent opens. I have looked at several examples and my code seems to match what I am seeing in many of the tutorials. Here is the code for the activity.

```
package com.honeydewit;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
import com.honeydewit.adapters.ListItemAdapter;
import com.honeydewit.listeners.OneOffClickListener;
import com.honeydewit.pojos.BasicList;
import com.honeydewit.pojos.ListItem;

public class ListHomeActivity extends BasicActivity{
   private ImageButton addItemBtn;
    private ImageButton addByScanBtn;
        private ArrayList<ListItem> lists = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        public static  ListItemAdapter listAdapter;
private TextView headerTxt;
private BasicList basicList;
private ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listshome);
    listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    basicList = getApplicationContext().getCurrentList();
    headerTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headerTxt);
    headerTxt.setText(basicList.getName());
    headerTxt.setTypeface(getApplicationContext().getTypeface());
    //add button
    addItemBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add);
    addItemBtn.setOnClickListener(new OneOffClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            addToList(v, basicList);

        }
    });
    addByScanBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addByScan);
    addByScanBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    addByScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new OneOffClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            addToListByScan(v, basicList);

        }
    });
    setupListAdapter(basicList.get_id());


}


private void setupListAdapter(int listId) {
    populateListItems(listId);
    listAdapter = new ListItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, lists);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}


private void populateListItems(int listId) {
    ArrayList<ListItem> items = (ArrayList<ListItem>)getApplicationContext().getShoppingListDbHelper().getShoppingListItems(listId);
    for(ListItem item : items ) {
        lists.add(item);
    }
}


private void addToList(View view, BasicList list) {

    if(basicList.getListTypeId() == Constants.TODO_LIST_TYPE_CDE) {
        Intent newListIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ToDoItemActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(newListIntent, 1);
    }
    else {
        Intent newListIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ItemActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(newListIntent, 1);
    }

}
private void addToListByScan(View view, BasicList list) {
    try {

        IntentIntegrator zxingIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);  
        zxingIntegrator.initiateScan();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR:" + e, 1).show();

    }

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), scanResult.getContents());
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), scanResult.getFormatName());
            Log.d(getClass().getName(),data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(),data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
        }
    }

}



}
```

Comment: I found the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910840/android-startactivityforresult-immediately-triggering-onactivityresult

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult` is called by *Android* whenever your app needs to be told about an `Intent`. That could be from lots of places. You know by looking at the request code and comparing it to the one in `IntentIntegrator`. Or let that class do all this for you.

My guess is your `intent-filter` is too broad and you're hearing things you don't expect.