# Android start activity for result not working correctly for translucent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I launch an `Activity` B from `Activity` A with `startActivityForResult()` and `Activity` B is translucent then Activity's A method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {}
```

works immediately even `Activity` B is open.

Please suggest.

Comment: Share your code so that we can help you.

Comment: What is there in your second Activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem. I solved it by removing the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag from the intent used to call Activity B. You could also check if there is 
    `singleInstance`
or
    `singletop`
in your manifest in Activity B.

"You can't use startActivityForResult() if your activity is being launched as a singleInstance or singleTop."

Source : [Android - startActivityForResult immediately triggering onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910840/android-startactivityforresult-immediately-triggering-onactivityresult)