# FragmentActivity getting killed automatic immediate after startActivityForResult?

Tags: android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, onactivityresult, start-activity

Note: This may be repeated but I did not found any solution for behaviour I have.

I am writing an simple application, where Using two FragmentActivity. Activity-A has two fragment A and B, both used public method of parent Activity for transaction.

Scenario defined as:

- **Activity A** Launch with **Fragment-A** as an child.
- Once **Fragment-A** is done, it call public method of parent **Activity-A**, which launch **Activity-B** using `startActivityForResult(intent, 101)`

Both of activity not defined `as singleInstance or singleTop` mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7910905/2624806).

**Recent Analysis:**

- In case if kept fragment child in Activity-B then it automatic
  finish(after some second delay), and that's why onActivityResult get called for Activity-A
- If I kept Activity-B without any Fragment Child then it work fine, no
  immediate calling of startActivityForResult.

---

**CLOSE**: It was mistake, I kept timer which causing problem.