# startActivityForResult() immediately call OnActivityResult when call another app

Tags: android

I have 2 app, `A` and `B`.

in app `A`, I want to call app `B` and get result from app `B`. I try this Code:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.B");
startActivityForResult(launchIntent, CODE);
```

but after I called that code, the onActivityResult() method called immediately and give result `RESULT_CANCELLED`.

App B manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.B">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

App B TestActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    if (getCallingActivity() == null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just add `launchIntent.setFlags(0);` before `startActivityForResult()` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24312398/4951966)

Answer (score 1):

That is what you have coded for..
Once the Activity of B app is launched you have called the setResult method because it is in the onCreate() method..
The reason you are getting failed result code is because you have set

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
```

but you should have used Activity.RESULT_OK like

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getCallingActivity()
```

woun't be null only in case if you would call the specific Activity with your startActivityForResult Intent.
 But you are calling not the specific activity, but `getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.B");`
which retrieves the default launch activity of the specified package, and starts it with default(empty) intent.