# Android preference startActivityForResult always return data null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-preferences

I have an issue with the image picker from preference activity. I created a preference and when click on it, application will go to image picker screen. But when I pick an image there is no data is retrieved.

Here is my code which call to startActivityForResult

```
Preference chooseImageFromGal = (Preference) findPreference("pref_key_background_device");
    chooseImageFromGal.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            SettingActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser( intent, "Select Picture"), IMAGE_FROM_DEVICE);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here is my onActivityResultFunction. The imageReturnedIntent is null and resultCode = 0.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
           Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        if(imageReturnedIntent == null)
            Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(requestCode == IMAGE_FROM_DEVICE) {

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                                   selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the result

[image]

I have no idea why function onActivityResult run on this screen. My code work fine on orther project. Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say "no data is retrieved".  Is `onActivityResult()` called?  Is the result code `RESULT_OKAY`?  Is the selected image `Uri` null?  Is the cursor result of the query null or empty?

Comment: As you see in `onActivityResult` function, if `imageReturnedIntent` is null then the toast is shown. Another problem is `resultCode` = 0

Comment: Have you seen this [related issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910840/android-startactivityforresult-immediately-triggering-onactivityresult)?  Does your `PreferenceActivity` have `launchMode` in the manifest set to `singleTop` or `singleInstance`?

Comment: WOW. It is exactly what I want. Thanks you so much to rescue me from a hard week :)